How to have two backup copies in rman for disk and tape?
Is there a way to backup a database and have two copies of the backup? One for disk and other for tape?
I have the following command, but I'd like to change /backup2 to a tape instead of disk
run{
SET BACKUP COPIES = 2;
backup as compressed backupset database format '/backup1/db_full%U.bkp','/backup2/db_full%U.bkp' plus archivelog format '/backup1/arc%U.bkp','/backup2/arc%U.bkp';
backup current controlfile format '/backup1/controlfile_%U.bkp','/backup2/controlfile_%U.bkp';
}

